# FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION : No permission to send the Email based on the Case

Tags: email, validation-rule, error, email2case

The functionality Email-to-case is not working for me. When I am sending a Case to e-mail, a new case is not created. I am using the long service e-mail. When I changed the Automated Case User to myself I am getting following error to my e-mail:

The following errors were encountered while processing an incoming email:

FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION : No permission to send the Email based on the Case.

**I found an answer that a Validation Rule is causing it, does somebody know how to come to the point on which object this validation rule may be? I have thousands of objects and validations rules on my org...**

Thank you in advice for any tip!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a validation rule **or** a trigger. It would be on the EmailMessage object either way. I would suggest [downloading the metadata](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev/sfdx_app_dev_setup_dx) for EmailMessage, ApexTrigger, ApexClass, and CustomLabel, and do a search for the error message. If you don't want to download the metadata, you can still find this in the UI, but it will be substantially more challenging to find it.